Angular 17 upgrade | Internationl Telephone numbers | Ng2TelInputModule deprecated
I am performing an upgrade from Angular 15 to 17.
One of the modules has Ng2TelInputModule which has been deprecated in Angular 17 material and doesnt work.
I tried using NgxIntlTelInputModule and added below in the appComponent.html

`getInputObject(obj) {
    this.telObject = obj;
}`

getInputObject embeds the object to existing value of Telephone entered before.
styles in angular.json
`"node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css"`

scripts :
`"scripts": [
              "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/intlTelInput.min.js"
            ]`

when i launch this is returns screen as below :

and the screem remains frozen, nothing happens when I click the dropdown.
can someone suggest where i could be going wrong or plz suggest an alternative library i could use for angular 17.
I tried all the above and it doesnt seem to work
